# Paypal Merchant account prevent multiple billing agreements

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a sandbox paypal account configured for reference transactions, and creating the billing agreement is fine.

Does paypal offer a way for us to prevent the same paypal customer account from being used for multiple billing agreements?

The reason for this is two fold. For any given customer on our side, we only want to have one paypal billing agreement. Also, no two customers on our side should link to the same paypal customer account.

Cheers,
Damian

Answer (score 2):

If you set the `BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION` to be the same for all the transactions a buyer shouldn't be able to sign up twice.

If you have a system where buyers sign into your site you can do a `GetBillingAgreementCustomerDetails` to see if the buyer already has a billing agreement with you. If they do,  you submit a Reference Transaction. If they don't, you create a new billing agreement.

Comment: I have my billing agreement setup with 
billingType = MERCHANTINITIATEDBILLINGSINGLEAGREEMENT

Comment: I have my billing agreement setup with 
billingType = MERCHANTINITIATEDBILLINGSINGLEAGREEMENT
and the description is consistent.

This results in any repeat attempts of agreeing to a new billing agreement returning the same billingAgreementID. 

Are you saying it is the description that does this and not the billingType?

Either way, that is useful. However, is there a way for us to actually prevent the customer from actually agreeing to the paypal agreement if it turns out they already have one with us?

Comment: For Example:

CustomerA is on our site, we setExpressCheckout with a billingAgreement. He is redirected and logs in as PaypalA. We get the billingAgreementID in the response and store against CustomerA.

Later on CustomerB comes to our site, we setExpressCheckout with a billingAgreement, He is redirected and logs in AGAIN as PaypalA.

When CustomerB agrees we will get a success response, with the same billingAgreement as CustomerA.

Is there a way after being redirected and logging in to paypal, if that customer already has a billingAgreement with us Paypal will not allow them to continue?